# Van Der waals forces

Tags: water

Dipoles occur in the formation Van Der waals forces. Van Der waals forces are said to cause clusters of water molecules to form even in liquid water. If this is correct then why don't we see increase in viscosity as water decreases in temperature?

Answer (score 1):

But there is an increase in viscosity at lower temperatures. And this is indeed attributed to stronger hydrogen bonding and larger clusters. According to Martin Chaplin, my favorite site about water: http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/physical_anomalies.html#Tvisc

Comment: Site can't be reached. Can you update the link?

Comment: @DavidJonsson That would be a pity if it was gone. Recently archived http://web.archive.org/web/20201210040133/http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/

Comment: @DavidJonsson And this specific page: http://web.archive.org/web/20201112014247/http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/physical_anomalies.html#Tvisc

Comment: Fine, but why don't you edit your answer?